# Why 'git-merge-file current base other' make an empty 'current' file if current = base = other?

Tags: git, merge

Well, imagine 
current.txt file :

```
asdf
```

base.txt file :

```
asdf
```

other.txt file :

```
asdf
```

when I do a three-way merge with

```
git merge-file current.txt base.txt other.txt
```

current.txt file become empty, why ? 
In other case current.txt file become a merge of the 3 files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a bug in `git merge-file`, but not one that is every going to be triggered in practice.

`git merge-file` is not a command targetted for end user use but is used internally by git as part of a merge or rebase activity. It will only be called on files that have actually changed so passing three files to `git merge-file` that all have identical contents won't happen in practice.

EDIT: I've proposed a patch to fix this, although it will need expert review: [gmane link](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/119879/focus=119880)

EDIT: This bug will be fixed in v1.6.3.2 and later versions of git.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in git-merge-file, to me. You should ask this question on the git mailing list. I think you're likely to get a better answer there. The guys that monitor that list are pretty sharp and would know whether or not this is intended behavior.